# How can I add an item to the Startup list in MSConfig?

Tags: windows-7, boot, msconfig

I've got a small console application that runs some SVN commands on a number of folders that I run first thing in the morning. Is it possible to add this to the list of things Windows runs at startup?

Edit; Downloading the Tortoise SVN PDF now and I'll see if I can "translate" my app to a batch script, if that's an easier to run automatically at startup.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**NB:** a faster way would be to add a link to the file in `C:\Users(User-Name)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Regarding your question:
you can add the path to the application in the windows registry:

1) hit **Start**

2) type **regedit** and press enter

3) go to
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

4) In the right pane of Run, right click on a blank spot and add a new key, containing the path to your application

Detailed guide [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1401-startup-programs-change.html).

Comment: you're welcome sab. a faster way would be to add a link to the file in 
C:\Users\(User-Name)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Comment: Is there a practical difference between adding it to the Startup folder versus editing the registry?

Answer (score 2):

You can add/remove an item to the Startup list in MSConfig with regedit :

On regedit you have several path :

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` (like Jess's answer)
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` only 64bits
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

Unchecked elements on msconfig.exe, are here : `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\MSConfig\startupreg`

- [Remove Unchecked Items from MSConfig](http://www.pcworld.com/article/255514/remove_unchecked_items_from_msconfig.html)

And with windows folder : `C:\Users\(User-Name)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Answer (score 2):

This page has the steps mentioned in detail. This is by far the best method of adding a program to startup because you also get the option to disable it from msconfig by a simple checkbox uncheck

Source: http://nofusswintricks.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-add-program-to-windows-startup.html

**Step 1:**

Start regedit:

Press “Win + R” or Start button > Run

**Step 2:**

To run only for current user:

In regedit, go to:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

To run for all users, go to:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

**Step 3:**

Right Click > New > String Value

and then type name of the program e.g.: “Sticky Notes”

Right Click > Modify

now enter the full path of the program e.g.:”C:\Windows\System32\StikyNot.exe”

Now your program should start the next time you restart your PC

Comment: Nice link! However, we discourage link-only answer, because if the link is broken, then your answer will be invalidated and might be deleted. Can you update your answer to include the essential part/summary of the link mentioned?

Comment: included text from the link

Comment: Although it is essentially the same answer, +1 for better readability.