# Pop-up icons for caps lock, scroll lock, volume, etc. disappeared after running an uninstallation file for a program that was never installed. why?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, file-corruption

I have windows 7. Everything is currently updated and to be frank this is quite embarrassing. I should've gotten this fixed back in 2013 when it happened. Hopefully the updates over the years haven't made it impossible to undo the damage.

So before I get into what I've noticed in the aftermath of this, I'll explain exactly what I did that caused it:

Back in 2012-2013 I was using the program Game Maker (the *exact* version I was using can be found archived [here](http://auntiepixelante.com/?p=1240)). I had uninstalled it on this computer and I still had it installed on another computer. Since that version was phased out from the engine's website, and I was using the free version I just copied the directory from one computer to the other. I know that sort of thing doesn't cause problems since technically an install is just there to set up special directories and file associations. It wasn't necessary for that program.

However, because the program's icon and the uninstalation file's icon were the very similar, I accidentally clicked uninstall. It did uninstall the program but it also caused some problems.

Since then my computer has stopped showing [the pop-ups](http://i1187.photobucket.com/albums/z382/f1rz3n_0028/capslock.jpg) that would occur when I press certain keys like caps lock, scroll lock and the volume adjustment. I can still see the volume in this bottom right like on most computers. However, I believe the on screen popups have been deleted from my computer somehow due the uninstall messing with my computer.

Is there some way to reinstall the feature or some kind of batch script to recode that portion of the OS. I don't really know if that feature can be turned on/off. I'm assuming not, which is why I believe that it's an issue with some file on my computer getting corrupted.

If anyone knows why this occurred (I'm genuinely curious), or how to fix it that would be great. I'd love to have those icons back on my computer and it's annoying that I have no means to detect when my caps lock gets hiT BY ACCIDENT.

Below is an image I found of the original volume icon. It would appear in the center of the screen regardless of what program I had open. This was similar to how the num lock, scroll lock, and caps lock looked.

[image]

This was built into my computer. It was there from day one. It is windows 7. It was bought in late 2010 and is a Gateway NV59C computer. I don't know if that is correct. The labels are still on the hand-rest thing so I assume that might be relevant. I just assumed this was a windows 7 feature. Any clue what I might need to look in? I'd imagine the software is probably still on my computer somewhere. It's just that the stupid uninstall messed up some variable somewhere telling it to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible Cause**

These on-screen displays (OSD) are likely provided by Acer's Launch Manager. If this programme does not run automatically when Windows starts, you won't get any OSD yet the keys you press will function normally (to test that, level up/down the brightness; OSD won't show but the screen will light up/down).

**Suggested Solutions**

- To check if Launch Manager auto-starts up, press the `Win key + R` and type `msconfig` then OK. Go to the `Startup` tab and look for Launch Manager (or its exe name, perhaps LaunchManager.exe, lmaanger.exe, launchm.exe). However, make sure that there is a tick mark next to it then confirm your changes.
- If you are sure that Launch Manager is installed but it is not listed in `msconfig` and tab `Startup`, you can put its shortcut in the `Startup` folder in `Start > All Programs > Startup`. Right click that folder and choose `Open` and paste the shortcut inside the windows that popped-up.

[image]

- Also if you are sure that Launch Manager is installed and you prefer to enlist it in `msconfig` and tab `Startup`, press the `Win key + R` and type `regedit` then OK. Browse to the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` and right-click an empty space on the right pane, choose `new > String Value` and name it `LaunchManager`. Double-click this and paste the path to Launch Manager's .exe in the `Value Data` field. Do now the first suggested solution in this list.
- If Launch Manager does not exist in the `msconfig` Startup tab or the problem persists, consider re-installing the programme. Try to download form this [hot-link](http://global-download.gateway.com/GDFiles/Application/LaunchManager/LaunchManager_Dritek_4.0.14_W7x86W7x64_A.zip?acerid=634511315379027726&Step1=NOTEBOOK&Step2=NV%20SERIES&Step3=NV59C&OS=ALL&LC=en&BC=GATEWAY&SC=AAP_4G) I found for your Gateway NV59c's Launch Manager or go to [Gateway's support website](http://www.gateway.com/gw/en/MY/content/drivers-downloads) and look in the `Search by Product Model` section for your NV59c. Below the page there click Application and download Launch Manager. Then install it on your device.

Comment: I went to the msconfig like you said and it wasn't in the list. However, I then went to install the version from gateway's website and it stated that a version was already installed. is there somewhere else that could be causing the issue?

Comment: Since you suggested to use the msconfig, I looked up how to add things to the msconfig startup and found these instructions. https://superuser.com/questions/689108/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-the-startup-list-in-msconfig. I went into the registry and altered HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run. That looks like it solved the problem. Thanks for pointing me in that direction.

Comment: @Typhon I was about to edit my answer to add the instruction on doing that. Yet more importantly, do OSDs now show properly now after restarting?

Comment: Yes, they now show up upon restarting and the program is in msconfig's list. I'm going to assume that the program was "uninstalled" due to the uninstallation file using a particular program ID and installing that and by chance launch manager had that index on that computer. Would you consider that to be an accurate reason as to why the OSDs disappeared to begin with? Mostly I just want to make sure nothing "hidden" was also damaged/altered.

Comment: @typhon it's very unlikely that uninstalling one programme would interrupt another programme's function. It only happens due to the work of anti-adware or so-called system cleaner software. If you happen to run a system cleaner, for example, make sure you check what it cleans especially the registry, or, better yet, avoid using it!

Comment: Please don't make wild guesses about what might have caused my problem. I know that is what caused 100% for a fact because it literally happened right when I ran the uninstall. Read my question. It was an uninstall file for a program *that wasn't installed at the time*. I've never ran a system cleaner, specifically because I used it on a different computer it deleted half of my java 3D graphics rendering source code files because it thought they were "adware". Please do not rudely assume that something else caused my problem when I know exactly what I did that led to it happening.

Comment: The only reason I don't know everything that it did is because I've never written nor seen the internals of an uninstalll program before so I don't know what it could do in the case that it was being used (accidentally) to uninstall a program that wasn't installed. Please do not treat me like I'm stupid. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a full answer. However, after researching a little bit, I've found the following link that definitely clears up exactly what broke:

http://community.acer.com/t5/Swift-Spin-S-and-R-Series/How-to-DISABLE-Caps-lock-and-Num-lock-screen-notifications-on-my/td-p/419415

I then went to the directory given in that forum:

"C:\Program Files(x86)\LaunchManager"

I took the following screenshot:

[image]

Going into details mode nothing was edited since the PC was (I assume) pre-installed as everything has pre-2012 dates as last modified. So this definitely was not altered. It is definitely the software that needs to be fixed. When I run the "LManager.exe" program, everything works again. However, it does not running on between startups. Notifications for sound and keyboard keys are back. So I suspect that the uninstallation corrupted something in either the environment variables or the registry regarding whatever in Windows made that program run during startup.

Hopefully someone can find how to turn this back on. This is technically an answer, but I do want to get the computer back into the original state it had for this where it would start it up. I wouldn't be surprised if other things also got messed up at the same time. Hence, finding where this was disabled is very important to me.

Answer (score 1):

Basic Windows 7 does not have these popups, so they are
definitely from some pre-installed software.
If this is, as you suspect, Launch Manager,
then I believe that it can be found over the Internet.

As Launch Manager still exists on your computer,
I suspect that the problem can be solved by registering some DLL,
or more simply by running again its installation (which you don't have).

You may, as a first try,
[run regSvr32](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/249873/how-to-use-the-regsvr32-tool-and-troubleshoot-regsvr32-error-messages)
with the DLLs in the installation folder of Launch Manager.
No harm will come from doing that. For example, run in Command Prompt (cmd)
that is Run as administrator:

```
regsvr32 LMLang.dll
```

For finding the installation of your version of Launch Manager,
let us know its version number,
as there is a very good chance of finding it for download.
A quick search found several versions of  it, but the best link may be
[Launch Manager 7.0.12](http://launch-manager.updatestar.com/en).
This is the latest version, released on 11/28/2014,
later than yours,
but this website also includes all previous versions.
Installing a newer version than the one you have could be a bonus.

I have to warn that a
[scan by VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/3e3cc35d759ca08a286c693ce0058e7ee5b432310afd5cff46fdd4fe4328df)
flagged the download as containing adware.
However, the
[Wikipedia article for UpdateStar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UpdateStar)
does not contain any warnings about that website.

As a precaution, backup first the installation folder of Launch Manager
that you found. Create also a system restore point, so you can go back
to your actual version.